# Valgrind invalid write error with array of pointers to structs

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm getting an error (well, a ton of errors actually) from valgrind that I'm having trouble sorting out.

I'm using this code to declare a struct:

```
struct HashTableT {

HashFuncT hashFunc;
// array of SortedList's
SortedListPtr* arrayPtr;
};

typedef struct HashTableT* HashTable;
```

arrayPtr is meant to be a pointer to an array of pointers to other structs.
Then allocating memory for it later with this:

```
HashTable index;
index = malloc(sizeof(HashTable));
memcheck(index);
index->hashFunc = func;
index->arrayPtr = malloc(sizeof(SortedListPtr) * size);
memcheck(index->arrayPtr);
// initialize array
int i;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    index->arrayPtr[i] = NULL;
}
return index;
```

Valgrind is giving me this error:

```
==18735== Invalid write of size 4
==18735==    at 0x80497F1: HTCreate (chainedhash.c:35)
==18735==    by 0x8049727: main (main.c:457)
==18735==  Address 0x402e02c is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==18735==    at 0x4005B83: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==18735==    by 0x804979B: HTCreate (chainedhash.c:32)
==18735==    by 0x8049727: main (main.c:457)
```

Line 35 is the one with the malloc statement.  It's seems to me that I'm allocating, not writing so the error is confusing me and I can't figure out what to do about it.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
index = malloc(sizeof(HashTable));
```

Malloc's enough memory for a *pointer*, not your struct.

This also illustrates why typedefs that hide the type like this make things confusing.

Comment: I wasn't trying to allocate memory for the other structs yet.  My intention in this part of the code was to allocate memory for the HashTable struct and the array of pointers.

Comment: Correct, and as I pointed out above, you're not doing that. You're malloc'ing `index = malloc(sizeof(HashTableT*))` (if you strip away the typedef) which is the size of a pointer not your struct. You then try and use `index->arrayPtr` which is going to be outside the memory you malloc'd. At this point Bad Things happen.

Comment: Ah, now I understand.  Changing it to `sizeof(struct HashTableT)` sorted the error out.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: To add: You can change it to: `index = malloc(sizeof(*index))` and you'll get the correct amount of memory (or, `sizeof(struct HashTableT)` ).

Comment: No problem. In general, using typedef like that may seem convenient, but it makes things less obvious down the road.